# linkedin page crawling with jsoup doesn't return body information

Tags: java, jsoup, linkedin-api

I am trying to crawl my company's linkedin page by means of jsoup. When I try the code given below, i cannot reach the desired html file. The returned html file is containing only top header and footer. The information in between does not show up.

How should I tackle this?

Here is my code:

```
String url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?goback=&trk=hb_signin";

Connection.Response response = Jsoup
          .connect(url)
          .method(Connection.Method.GET)
          .execute();

Document responseDocument = response.parse();

Element loginCsrfParam = responseDocument
         .select("input[name=loginCsrfParam]")
          .first();

response = Jsoup.connect("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit")
           .cookies(response.cookies())
           .data("loginCsrfParam", loginCsrfParam.attr("value"))
           .data("session_key", "MY_EMAIL")
           .data("session_password", "MY_PASSW")
           .method(Connection.Method.POST)
           .followRedirects(true)
           .execute();

Document document = response.parse();

     System.out.println("Welcome " 
                                + document.select(".act-set-name-split-link").html());        

        String url2 = "https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?type=all&keywords=BARCO+NV+kortrijk";

        Response response2 = Jsoup.connect(url2)
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21")
            .timeout(100*1000)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .execute();

        Document docc = response2.parse();

        String html = docc.html();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url2)
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21")
            .timeout(100*1000)
            .get();

        String htmlstring = doc.html();
```

Comment: What is the url that doesn't work?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?type=all&keywords=BARCO+NV+kortrijk when i go to this link on my chrome browser i can see all the employees. But in my code given as url2 i cannot reach that information.

Comment: Does the url redirects you on the login page?

Comment: It seems it does not. Now I have stumbled upon that in the html i got from my code there is a part seeming contain the information having kind a different structure. <div id="srp_main_" class=""> 
     <code id="voltron_srp_main-content" style="display:none;">
      <!--{"content...THIS IS A VERY LONG TEXT POSSIBLY CONTAINING THE INFO IN QUESTION end","lix_header_lowercase":"control","lix_instant_co......<script id="voltron_srp_main" type="fs/embed+m"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">fs.embed("voltron_srp_main","tl/apps/search/voltron/embed/srp_main");</script> 
    </div>.